# Saxon input encoding not recognized?

Tags: xml, xslt, utf-8, saxon, windows-1252

I get weird characters in a utf-8 text output from Saxon xslt processor.

The input xml is headed with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
```

It contains strings like (shown in notepad++ with Windows-1252 encoding shown down right)

```
“abc”
```

The transformation stylesheet contains

```
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
```

but the output contains (shown in notepad++ with UTF-8 encoding shown down right)

```
ï¿½abcï¿½
```

instead of UTF-8 encoded

```
“abc”
```

Any idea what I missed?

p.s.: when I use notepad++ to change the xml input from windows-1252 to UTF-8, the output is encoded correctly, and that is my workaround. However I'd like to understand whether I missed something or some software should be improved regarding character sets.

Comment: So how do you use Saxon exactly, do you use its command line tool with e.g. `-o:result.txt` to create the text file? Or do you write Java or C# code? You might need to provide the details on that to allow anyone to tell where things go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that although the input is labelled as being windows-1252, it isn't actually Windows-1252.

First, try to find out whether the problem is on input or on serialization. You can do that by using `string-to-codepoints()` within the XSLT code to see what actual codepoints are present in the parsed node tree.

If it's an input problem, then that's the responsibility of the XML parser rather than Saxon itself, so it depends on which XML parser you are using.

Comment: Thank you, Michael, that helped. I am calling Saxon from Java via the API. And reading the input file seems to be my problem.

Comment: How are you supplying the input? Perhaps you're doing the decoding yourself (rather than letting the XML parser do it) by supplying a Reader rather than an InputStream?

Comment: I will follow this idea - asap. The reasons to use Java-API are not only with CharSet problems but also being able to start Saxon even without an input, or with a pure text input e.g. .csv, or with text containing gt lt etc. characters to be passed to the output, or text input with markups that have to be converted to xml prior to applying xslt transformation. Hence, my InputStream check algorithm has a long history. In parts it may be outdated, but it works (most of the time).